# How to create/read a number with specific decimals without using strings?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to do the following SPOJ Problem:

https://www.spoj.com/problems/GUANGGUN/

The problem is, I have no idea how to properly create a number with specific decimals (for example: if `4` is inputted to a console, it would create `1.1111`, or in case of input of `8`: `1.11111111`). I tried to do it with `string`s, but it exceeded the **punishing time limit** of this problem.

But even then I don't know how to read a decimal at specific place without making it a string and using `variable[x]`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I've entered a following code as a solution:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;

namespace SPOJG
{
    class Program
    {
        private static long Formula(long n) => 81 * (n / 9) + (n % 9) * (n % 9);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool takeInputs = true;

            Queue inputs = new Queue();

            while (takeInputs)
            {
                string inputString = Console.ReadLine();

                int n;
                bool isNumber = int.TryParse(inputString, out n);

                if (isNumber)
                {
                    inputs.Enqueue(inputString);
                }
                else
                {
                    while (inputs.Count > 0)
                    {
                        GUANGGUN(Convert.ToInt32(inputs.Dequeue()));
                    }

                    takeInputs = false;
                }
            }
        }

        static void GUANGGUN(int input)
        {
            var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
              .Range(input, 1)
              .Select(n => $"{Formula(n),1}"));

            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

However, SPOJ says it's a wrong answers. Any ideas?

Comment: You are looking for https://oeis.org/A080151

Comment: for given `n` the sum is `81 * (n / 9) + (n % 9) * (n % 9)` where `/` is integer division, and `%` remainder

Comment: If `n` is up to `1e18`, then you should use `long`, not `int`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). As we can see in the initial problem

https://www.spoj.com/problems/GUANGGUN/

the `n` can be up to `1e18`; and that's why

```
11....1 (n times)
```

is a bit *too long* for *brute force* approach (`1e18` digits is a `string` of `1.7` **PetaByte** size). Actually, you are looking for [A080151](https://oeis.org/A080151) sequence, the code is

```
private static long Solution(long n) => 81 * (n / 9) + (n % 9) * (n % 9);
```

**Demo:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

var demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
  .Range(1, 15)
  .Select(n => $"{n,2} -> {Solution(n),3}"));

Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 1 ->   1
 2 ->   4
 3 ->   9
 4 ->  16
 5 ->  25
 6 ->  36
 7 ->  49
 8 ->  64
 9 ->  81 <- Example from the problem
10 ->  82 <- Example from the problem
11 ->  85
12 ->  90
13 ->  97
14 -> 106
15 -> 117
```

Comment: I've tested the code that I added in an edit of this topic's main post, however SPOJ thinks it's a wrong answer. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well strings would really be painfull if we talk about large input
Though there is solution to that using negative power of 10;

```
var Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Stopwatch.Start();
        double res = 1.0;
        input = input * -1;
        for (int i = input; i < 0; i++)
        {
            res += Math.Pow(10, i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(res);
        Stopwatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = Stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

You see, each next digit corresponds to a less power by absolute value of your input
so, for `4` you get `1 + 0.0001 + 0.001 + 0.01 + 0.1`